# Jenkins - Dynamic Extended Choice parameter to populate multi-level multi-select list

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to use the [Dynamic (Moded) Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) to bind with an [Extended Choice Parameter](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) multi-level field to populate the first level's list?

For example if I had:

[image: Moded extended choice parameter]

This would bind with this field below:

[image: Extended choice multi level]

Either by having the first level (Choice) default with their ModedChoice selection (Choice1,Choice2,Choice3), or based on their ModedChoice selection 'Value1' would be populated (I would take the Choice level out in that case).

I know the second method I mentioned can be done for a single select list as described on the [wiki](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin) and it would search for the text file Choice1.txt, Choice2.txt etc., which would contain Value1 values (i.e. key=value1.1,value1.2,value1.3  etc).

I couldn't figure out how to have that key contain a multi level list since it is a tab delimited format to separate columns, i.e:

```
Choice    Value1    Value2
choice1    value1.1    value2.1
choice1    value1.1    value2.2
choice2    value1.2    value2.1
choice2    value1.1    value2.5
choice3    value1.2    value2.7
```

etc..

I tried something like (Choice1.txt):

```
key='Value1    Value2
value1.1    value2.1
value1.1    value2.2
value1.2    value2.1
value1.1    value2.5
value1.2    value2.7'
```

etc.. for Choice2.txt and Choice3.txt.

But this just populates the multi level with `Value1 Value2`.

I tried binding with another Moded Choice Parameter (Multi Select), and left the Key field empty and kept the proper tab delimited format for the multi level select list, but it still outputs `Value1 Value2`.