# Jenkins Parameterize choice for the Deploying Servers

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops

I am working with Maven Project in Jenkins. Previously I configured maven build and Nexus Deployment. Now I want to deploy the project in deployment servers. There are four build environments called QA,Dev,Prod,Stress and each one have specific servers. Until this point I have made the selection properties using jenkins plugins.

[image: select]

The requirement is, when I select the deployment environment one by one as a example QA, I need to list down only QA servers, If it is stress I need to list down Stress Servers.

I am using extended choice parameter plugin.

Does anyone know how to do this?

In here I attach my deployment environment and servers.

[image: environ]

[image: servers]

Comment: I'm afraid there is no solution for this case, but you should take a look at this plugin : https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Extended+Choice+Parameter+plugin

Comment: Also, there is a similar SO topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26236506/jenkins-dynamic-extended-choice-parameter-to-populate-multi-level-multi-select

Comment: can't i write a if statement to do this? something like this. `if ( str eq 192.168.40.132) {
    host = QA;
} elsif ( str eq 192.168.40.133 ) {
    host = Dev;`

Comment: Isn't it the opposite ? `if(str == "QA"){ hosts = ["192.168.40.133","192.168.40.134", "..."}`

Comment: Yes, it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution for this. I think this will be important to future readers. For achieving this, I used,

1. Active Choices Plugin

Below I attached snapshots of the configuration.

[image: active1]

[image: active2]

[image: active3]